# Can't loop over object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
class SomeClass {
  myFunction() {
    console.log('Hello, World');
  }
}

for (let obj in SomeClass.prototype) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Hi everyone, I am trying to loop over class's prototype but it's not working, it doesn't give an error loop just won't execute, I tried running this code in dev tools same situation, what's wrong here, how do I loop over prototype object?

Comment: It's working exactly as intended - it loops over all enumerable properties. Of which there are none. With that said, it seems like a bit of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to achieve that requires going through the prototype properties?

Comment: I am writing some custom decorators and using reflect metadata npm package to wire up some decorators.

Comment: The OP could make use of e.g. [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)